# couchbase config with multiple network interface

Tags: couchbase

Having seen https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/membase/MvyK0d2IFa8 (which is quite old). I am faced with similar situation.

How can I configure couchbase to use physical network interface A (1.1.1.1) for all erlang cluster communications and network interface B (2.2.2.2) for HTTP and other client server communications including 8091 and management ports.

Hopping to find a better way than messing around with routing table.

TIA

Comment: This can't be done afaik. Often times, what you say you want and what you actually need are two different things. What is the reason for wanting to do this, maybe we can help you with simple alternatives?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am evaluating different erlang key-value DBs for a solution we are building for our client. The solution will be installed as an erlang cluster. The network/firewall policy of our client dictates that, of the two physical network interfaces provided in each server machine, port range rule can only be applied to the internal interface. All the system management console (including DB) needs to be accessed through the other interface which is accessible from public net (port range not allowed there). I was quite impressed with couchbase but this is a show stopper for us.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does the CB instance need to be accessible from outside the corporate firewall?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'couch base instance'. Access to the rest interface needs to be accessed by the application from a different firewall zone. Also for checking DB health replication status, trigger failover through webgui etc.

Comment: "Access to the rest interface needs to be accessed by the application from a different firewall zone."  <-- that's the part I don't understand - seems like a strange setup to me; why can't you locate them side-by-side on the same machine(s)??

Comment: For arguments' sake, lets say client agrees to adapt to couchbase interface configuration limitation. Running couch cluster over private interface and let application also connect through the same still does not answer how to access the couch management portal from outside?

Comment: Don't access the portal from outside - use a VPN. I've worked with clients in some of the most restrictive IT environments imaginable, and I have not had the issues you are having.

Comment: What can I say @rmayer06, that is how things rolls in that company :). but thanks a lot for helping clearing it up that couchbase is not flexible enough to be configured it that way. Its a shame but clearly  couchbase with this configuration restriction makes life a lot harder!

Comment: I'm glad I could give you pointers! But, don't blame Couchbase, you should never rely upon the configurability of a tool to provide for network architecture shortcomings! That's how security risks happen.

Comment: totally agree. and I am not blaming couchbase. just that its sad that I cant propose it in our solution design. thanks very much for all comments. hope these will at least save someone else from coming down this path

Comment: I still don't understand your issue though - I work with the government, and in my area we have the most restrictive IT environments you can imagine. We would be able to use CB with no issues. I can't possibly believe that there is some additional configuration constraint keeping you from using this. The problem has got to be somewhere in your system architecture.

Comment: Another thought - Have you tried virtualizing your server or network adapter (VMWare?)

Comment: we ended up decided to port forward 8091 (couchbase management) through external interface. thnx

Comment: OK, interesting. Communication over 8091 does not use SSL, just a heads-up.

Comment: :)... yup, waiting for my client to discover that... but I am thinking of proposing a SSL terminator together with the same port forward in the same linux box... how does that sound in your openion?